# How to return result from a stored procedure to TASK RETURN_VALUE in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I would like to return logging and status messages from a stored procedure to the TASK that calls it.

```
create or replace procedure status_return()
  returns string not null
  language javascript
  as
  $$
    var result_status = 'The return status and debug information in string format';
  return result_status; // Statement returned for info/debug purposes
  $$;
```

I would like to pass the result from stored procedure call `status_return()` back to the task

```
-- Create a task that calls the stored procedure every hour
create or replace  task call_SP
  warehouse = SMALL
  schedule = '1 minute'
as
call status_return();
```

When I execute TASK_HISTORY to view `RETURN_VALUE` is always empty.

```
select * 
from table(information_schema.task_history(SCHEDULED_TIME_RANGE_START => dateadd(hours, -5, current_timestamp()) , 
                               TASK_NAME => 'call_sp'));
```

[image]

How can I view the result of a stored procedure in `task_history` for SUCCESS, FAILURE, or ERRORS?

I have tried creating a task in the following way, but I was unsuccessful and it return with errors.

```
create or replace  task call_SP
  warehouse = EDS_SMALL
  schedule = '1 minute'
as
call system$set_return_value(call status_return());
```

Can I use Javascript in Tasks? To store the result of a stored procedure call into a variable and return it back to the TASK result

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able to get a **RETURN_VALUE** in your **TASK_HISTORY** you have to set the return_value in your stored procedure using `call system$set_return_value()`.
Examples can be found in [snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_set_return_value.html).

This is what it should looks like if you want the return_value field of the task_history to return your result status var when your task is launched :

```
create or replace procedure status_return()
  returns string not null
  language javascript
  as
  $$
  var result_status = 'The return status and debug information in string format';
  var rv_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:`call system$set_return_value('` + result_status  + `');`});
  var rv_res = rv_stmt .execute(); // Set return_value

  return result_status; // Statement returned for info/debug purposes
  $$;
```

Comment: How do I return a json/variant object in TASK_HISTORY, I tried this and it gave me :
` [object Object] `
in TASK_HISTORY RETURN_VALUE column